# React native responsive header height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to set my header height so its responsive for tablets and smartphones. I've have tried using flex column:

```
const headerStyle = {
  paddingHorizontal: theme.metrics.mainPadding,
  paddingTop: 0,
  paddingBottom: 0,
  backgroundColor: theme.colors.blue,
  flex: 0.5,
  flexDirection: 'column',
};
```

However, the header looks ok on a tablet but too tall on a smartphone.

What is the best way to set dimensions for different devices?

EDIT:

I have this function:

```
export function em(value: number) {
  return unit * value;
}
```

And I am now using it in my stylesheet:

```
  headerHeight: em(6),
  headerImageWidth: em(3),
  headerImageHeight: em(3),
  headerLogoHeight: em(6),
  headerLogoWidth: em(20),
```

The image looks ok on tablet, but now on smartphone its too small. If i understand correctly, I need to use dimensions.width to set an appropriate unit value in my function?

Smartphone[image: Smartphone]

Tablet[image: Tablet]

Comment: You will have to use the 'Dimensions' module from 'react-native' and modify your style at runtime. Responsive a la react-native. Here is a good read : https://medium.com/@elieslama/responsive-design-in-react-native-876ea9cd72a8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of two ways

**Using flex**

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={{flex:0.2}}>
     <Text>Header</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:0.8}} />

</View>
```

You have mentioned using flex, but not working. I am not sure how exactly as if you are using it like above, size should be relative to screen size.

**Using Dimensions**

How about using the `Dimensions` module. It can be used to get the `width` and `height` of the window and you can set height based on that

```
import {
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
const winWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const winHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;


header = {
    height: winHeight * 0.2 // 20%
}
```

Then use width and height to set the height of the header (ex. percentage-based)